# in supabase, difference between anon and public

Tags: next.js, supabase

recently, i beginning to develop some service with supabase.

on local supabase dashboard,

[situation]

when i add new policy on A table as below

- target: (Defaults to all (public) roles if none selected).
- operation: update
- using expression: true
- with check expression: true

it works as expected so i can update row in my client

but when i add new policy on A table as below

- target: anon
- operation: update
- using expression: true
- with check expression: true

i cant update row in my client..

[question]

1. i want to know what is difference between anon and public role
2. if i miss something please let me know

[environment]

- client: nextjs
- auth-helper: @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs
- .env.local
- NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=
- NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=

[code]
`
const supabase = createServerActionClient({
cookies,
});

supabase.from('A').update({col: 'value'}).eq('col', col)
`

Answer (score 0):

There is no role called `public`, and the "Defaults to all (public) roles" just means that if you don't specify a target role, the RLS policy will be applied to all roles that are public. You can learn more about roles [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/roles#supabase-roles).

- The user on your application is signed in, and therefore does not have the anon role.
- You have not granted `select` policy to the user. The user needs both update and select permission to update a row.